# Help Solving First Order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$e^y + [t e^y -sin(y)] \frac{dy}{dt}=0 \quad y(2)=1.5$

Is it possible to find an exact solution to this ODE using some method?

**Following Adriano's hint: (second edit)**

$d( e^y t + cos(y) ) =0$
or
$e^y t + cos(y)=c_1 $ for some constant $c_1$

and then using the initial value condition

$c_1 = e^{1.5} 2 + cos(1.5)$

So we have the relation

$e^y t + cos(y) = e^2 1.5 + cos(2)$

which satisfies the ODE.

or $ t = e^{-y} [-cos(y)+e^{1.5} 2 + cos(1.5)]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Yes. Note that this ODE is exact, since by rewriting it as:
$$
\underbrace{[e^y]}_{M}dt + \underbrace{[t e^y - \sin(y)]}_N dy=0
$$
we observe that it has the form $M(t,y)~dt + N(t,y)~dy = 0$, where:
$$
M_y = e^y = N_t
$$
Now try to find a function $\psi(t,y)$ such that $\psi_t = M$ and $\psi_y = N$. Once you have done this, you can apply product rule in reverse.

Comment: am I doing this right? Thx

Comment: Almost, you just switched the $t$ and $y$. You should get that:
$$
c_1 = 2e^{1.5} + \cos(1.5)
$$

Comment: does this fall under common sense eye-balling approach to solving ODE or does this have a name like a lot of methods have names? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I wouldn't call it common sense, but checking to see if an ODE is exact or not is a standard trick that people use when attempting to solve an ODE. Glad I could help. =]